# Unlimited sub domains

Tags: .htaccess, url, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain, rewriting

I'm currently setting up a webshop system and was thinking about making subdomains for these users. As I have done this a few times in the past I started of with the same code but for some reason it's not working out. Maybe someone here can shed some light on the mistaOptions +FollowSymLinks

```
Options +Indexes 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?testserver.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ ee [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.testserver.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).testserver.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.testserver.com/Webshops/index.php/store_example/%1/$1 [P,L]
```

I would like the subdomain to redirect to somewhere and add everything after it as well so for example:
testme.testserver.com/products/product-1 would be the url but would display http://www.testserver.com/Webshops/index.php/store_example/product/product-1

Anyone who has an idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: So in browser you want to show: `http://www.testserver.com/Webshops/index.php/store_example/product/product-1`?

Comment: No, I would like the browser to hide the real url and should still show testme.testserver.com/products/product-1

Comment: ok can you enable `mod_proxy` in your Apache web server?

Comment: unfortunately not I'm afraid, my hosting company doesn't want that because of security reasons...

Comment: In that case what you want is not possible.

Comment: To bad, thx for helping out :-)